# Need to update a json file by the given below condition

Tags: azure

1)we have a json file in the blobstorage we have to update the json file by giving the table name as input
2) update the particular given table    lasttrackingver  by passing the value
In AZUREDATA Factory
3)"lastupdate" column in the sample data needs to change for any table updated
4)"tableupdate" needs to update the particular  input table we are givingtable
sample data looks like

```
{
  "name" :"job schedule", 
  "lastupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z", 
  "schedule":{
  
    "BANKtable" :
    [
      { 
        "tablename":"mani",
       "pipeline":"manikana",
      "tableupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"0"
      },
    { 
        "tablename":"ganesh",
       "pipeline":"ganeshkulkarni",
      "tableupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"0"
      },
   { 
        "tablename":"jagadesh",
       "pipeline":"jaga",
      "tableupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"0"
      }
]
}
```

For example input :  tablename:ganesh
lasttrackingver=2

Output::::

```
{
  "name" :"job schedule", 
  "lastupdate": "TODAYSDATE", 
  "schedule":{
  
    "BANKtable" :
    [
      { 
        "tablename":"mani",
       "pipeline":"manikana",
      "tableupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"0"
      },
    { 
        "tablename":"ganesh",
       "pipeline":"ganeshkulkarni",
      "tableupdate": "TODAYSDATE",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"2"
      },
   { 
        "tablename":"jagadesh",
       "pipeline":"jaga",
      "tableupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"0"
      }
]
}
```

I have tried but it's not working....

Comment: You mentioned that you have tried. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried with dataflow and followed by flatten but  I'm not not sure how to do the scenario

Comment: what is your JSON file size? Is it more than 5000 rows?

Comment: It consist of 200 rows only

Comment: Please help me on this

Comment: Anyone please resond

Answer (score 0):

As your rows are less, you can try the below approach using lookup and ForEach.

First Use lookup on the JSON dataset(uncheck firstrow in lookup) and use filter activity on `BANKtable` array from the lookup output.

In filter activity, give the array in the items.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].schedule.BANKtable
```

And give the below expression in the condition of filter activity.

```
@and(equals(item().tablename,'ganesh'),equals(item().lasttrackingver,'2'))
```

It will give the matched objects as array.

[image]

As you are updating the `tableupdate` and `lastupdate` to the current date, take a set variable and store the current date in it with  `@utcnow()` expression.

Also, to update the `lastupdate`, first build a replaceable string and store in it a set variable. Use the below expression.

```
"lastupdate":"@{activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].lastupdate}"
```

This variable will be used to replace the `lastupdate` in the final JSON.

Now, Give the filter activity output array `@activity('Filter1').output.value` to a ForEach and click on sequential.

Inside ForEach, take another set variable activity and give the below expression.

```
@replace(string(item()),item().tableupdate,utcnow())
```

[image]

This will update the current item(object) `tableupdate` to the current date and the result object string will be stored in `rep_object` variable. Now use this to replace the current object in the JSON.

```
@replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]),string(item()),variables('rep_object'))
```

[image]

The result string will be stored in `json_str` variable.

So, in every iteration, the matched object will be replaced that means the `tableupdate` value will be updated to current date.

[image]

After ForEach, take an if activity. This is for checking whether any match found or not(if filter activity output array length greater than 0 that means match found). If match found, use copy activity to copy the updated JSON to the target file.

Use this expression in if activity.

```
@greater(length(activity('Filter1').output.value),0)
```

Inside True activities of if, take another set variable activity of string type and update the `lastupdate` using the below expression.

```
@replace(variables('json_str'),variables('lastupdate'),concat('"lastupdate": "',variables('curr_date'),'"'))
```

[image]

Now, take copy activity and for the **source of copy activity, take a sample csv file(with 1 header and 1 row)** in the blob.

In the additional columns, use the above string variable `final_json_str` like below.

[image]

For the **copy activity sink**, take another **delimited text dataset** with below configurations.

[image]

Name the file with `.json` type.

Give the below expression in the copy activity mapping dynamic content.

```
@json('{
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "mappings": [
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "new",
                                                "type": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String",
                                                "ordinal": 1
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }')
```

[image]

Now, execute the pipeline and the result JSON file will be generated.

[image]

**Use the below pipeline JSON to build your pipeline:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "JsonSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Source_json",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Filter1",
                "type": "Filter",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].schedule.BANKtable",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "condition": {
                        "value": "@and(equals(item().tablename,'ganesh'),equals(item().lasttrackingver,'2'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "lastupdate key",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Filter1').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Updated object",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "rep_object",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@replace(string(item()),item().tableupdate,utcnow())",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Update in JSON by replace",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Updated object",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "json_str",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]),string(item()),variables('rep_object'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "utcnow",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Filter1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "curr_date",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@utcnow()",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "lastupdate key",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "utcnow",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "lastupdate",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "\"lastupdate\":\"@{activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].lastupdate}\"",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "If Condition1",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@greater(length(activity('Filter1').output.value),0)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Update lastupdate in json",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "additionalColumns": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "new",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@variables('final_json_str')",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "value": "@json('{\n                                    \"type\": \"TabularTranslator\",\n                                    \"mappings\": [\n                                        {\n                                            \"source\": {\n                                                \"name\": \"new\",\n                                                \"type\": \"String\"\n                                            },\n                                            \"sink\": {\n                                                \"type\": \"String\",\n                                                \"physicalType\": \"String\",\n                                                \"ordinal\": 1\n                                            }\n                                        }\n                                    ],\n                                    \"typeConversion\": true,\n                                    \"typeConversionSettings\": {\n                                        \"allowDataTruncation\": true,\n                                        \"treatBooleanAsNumber\": false\n                                    }\n                                }')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "SampleSource",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "targetfile",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Update lastupdate in json",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "final_json_str",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@replace(variables('json_str'),variables('lastupdate'),concat('\"lastupdate\": \"',variables('curr_date'),'\"'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "rep_object": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "json_str": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "curr_date": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "lastupdate": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "final_json_str": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow great i will try thank you very much

Comment: I have created a pipeline but in filter  activity columns it's not filtering it's showing   "filtereditemscount":0

Comment: Use my pipeline JSON to build your pipeline. Make sure you have given correct expression in the filter activity items and condition.

Comment: Yeah I'm using the same one

Comment: Did it gave any error? share your expression and did you uncheck the firstRow in the lookup activity output?

Comment: No error.... @and(equals(item(). tablename, 'ETL_ADH_OUT_DIVISION'), equals(item(). lastchangetrackingversion, '2'))        and i unchecked the first row

Comment: Is your JSON data satisfying the filter conditions?

Comment: Yes it's satisfying and i dnt see any error but not able to see the filtered object

Comment: In look up I'm getting all the tables which are in the input file

Comment: Can you show your lookup output array and filter expressions by images?

Comment: It's working but in if condition we are getting an error we have to give the same file aa source and destination or we have to give different?

Comment: You need to use different files. Source file should contain only one header and one row.

Comment: No need to create target file, it will be generated automatically but give the above dataset configurations for the target file.

Comment: We have to update in the same file. The source and target is same

Comment: After generating the target Json file in the required format, after if activity you can use another copy activity to copy the target Json content to source(Overwrites the source data). But here, you need to use both datasets of JSON type.

Comment: I suggest you to first read the whole content of the answer and try later, so that you can understand it better.

Comment: Yeah I have removed if condition and directly connected to updatelastupdate activity and connected to web activity it is generating the required output       it's a great work thank you very much for the solution it helped me a lot..... 